# Reading and writing to a database using php with multiple includes

Tags: php, mysql, function, include

I am working on a website that lets users read and write to a database.

To sum it up, I am trying to accept an input from a user, write that to the database using a function included from a separate php file, and then be able to read that information using a different function from a separate php file. Code is below:

```
//Main php file that includes the files with functions
<?php
session_start();

$LastName = trim($_POST['LastName']);

include 'Functions/InsertName.php';
insertName($LastName); //Simply add the name to the database

include 'Functions/MoveFullName.php';
moveFullName($LastName); //Selects full name from database, inserts it into a different table

?>
```

Functions/InsertName.php code

```
<?php
session_start();

function insertName($Name) {
    require_once('../connect.php');
    $query = "INSERT INTO Names (LastName) VALUES ('$Name')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
}
```

Functions/MoveFullName.php code

```
<?php
session_start();

function moveFullName($Name) {
    require_once('../connect.php');
    $query2 = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Names WHERE LastName = '$Name'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $FirstName = $row['FirstName'];
    $LastName = $row['LastName'];

    $query3 = "INSERT INTO Accounts (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('$FirstName', '$LastName');
    $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $query3);
}
```

For some reason, it writes the names into the Names table just fine, but when I go to call the moveFullName function, nothing happens and the table of Accounts remains unchanged.

Do I need more time in between the function calls? Is it trying to grab information from the database before it is even there?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable error reporting while you are learning PHP (and for development in general):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

For your question - your `moveFullName` function expects argument:

```
function moveFullName($Name)
```

which you are not passing calling it:

```
include 'Functions/MoveFullName.php';
moveFullName();
```

Comment: Sorry I don't know how I missed copying that over but I had it in my code and it still didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Sure. check result from `mysli_query()`. If indicates failure, display what `mysqli_error()` returns.